# Array character as parameters in c

Tags: arrays, c, parameters

I have a problem with one thing, it works to compare a character in another function if I send it like '(' instead of an array character. Not the clearest description but look at the example code and you might understand.

```
char arr[5];
arr[0] = ")";

void func(){
  to_another_func("(");      
  to_another_func(&arr[0]);      
 }

void to_another_func(char*a) {
if(strcmp(a, "(") == 0)
printf("a is (");
}
```

According to me that's the same, if not, how can I make it the same?

Comment: What is the prototype for `to_another_func()`?

Comment: `to_another_func(arr[0]);`?

Comment: `to_another_func(&arr[0])` should compile at least with a warning. Anyway show a [mcve]

Comment: Oh its void to_another_func(char* a)

Comment: @AdamRöhr all clarifications should be _in the question_. You can [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: yeah so it is not exactly the same, because you use one opened bracket and one closed bracket, but it doesn't matter if you pass a character or a character variable.

Comment: `'('` is an int.  `&arr[0]` is a pointer to char.

Comment: The problem is that the code above doesn't work, it doesn't work to strcmp when a is arr[0]

Comment: I think you are looking for `to_another_func("(");`

Comment: @williampursell but '(' works and not &arr[0]

Comment: Undefined behavior often appears to work.  Passing `'('` as the 2nd argument of `strcmp` is incorrect, since the parameter ought to be a `char *`, but you are passing an int.

Comment: But the thing is "(" works but not when I use &arr[0]

Comment: That's because `arr[0] = ")"` is wrong.  You either want `char arr[5] = "(";` or `char arr[5]; arr[0] = '('; arr[1] = '\0';`

Comment: Or perhaps `char arr[5] = { '(', '\0' };`  I think you are confused about the difference between `"("` and `'('`.

Comment: **ALWAYS READ COMPILER WARNINGS** `warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    5 | arr[0] = ")";`